# Will Topographic Position Index (Tpi) not work in scattered raster layers?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, elevation, tpi

I have a non-continuous elevation raster layer and want to use `tpi` in the 
`spatialEco` package in R.

The elevation raster is in EPSG:5677 and looks like this:
[image]

I always get this (to me) rather cryptic error:

```
library(spatialEco)
tpi(elevation.raster,scale=150)
Error in .local(x, ...) : w must have uneven sides
```

I wonder if this is due to the raster layer being uncontinuous?

Comment: Could you show the summary info for your raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tpi` calls `focal` to do its work. If using a rectangular window, the `scale` parameter is in cells. If using a circular window, it calls `focalWeight` to get a matrix of weights but *that* uses CRS units.

So for a rectangular window, the default, you have to use an odd number in the `scale` parameter. For a circular window you use a distance in your CRS units and it can be anything (even decimal).

If you want a rectangular window of a given CRS distance, work out the number of cells that span that distance by using the `res` of your raster.

Here's the relevant chunk of `tpi`:

```
if (win == "circle") {
    if (scale < raster::res(x)[1] * 2) 
        stop("Scale is too small for a circular window")
    m <- raster::focalWeight(x, scale, type = c("circle"))
    m[m > 0] <- 1
}
else {
    m <- matrix(1, nrow = scale, ncol = scale)
}
```

Comment: @whyzar, he pulled it from the source code of the spatialEco::tpi function and is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

This error is originating from the raster::focal function. This is because window definitions for `window=rectangle` (default for window argument) need to be odd numbers (just like in a GIS) so, try `scale=151`. Although, this will be in pixels and not distance so you will need to make the pixel size to distance calculation to get the correct matrix dimensions for the window.

The focal function was not honoring matrices with NA's along the edges (defining a circular window) so, at this time I would not use win = "circle" and stay with "rectangle". The scale argument units for rectangle are in number of pixels where circle is in distance (radius) based on the projection of the raster.

All of the published literature, that I am familiar with, that has used TPI have used a rectangular window. I will however, check the circle argument for errors and look at output from focal to see if this bug has been addressed.

Comment: I don't think so. For rectangle, scale is pixels, for circle, scale is distance. See my answer.

Comment: @Spacedman, you are correct on units and I edited my answer to clarify. However, based on the syntax of the original post I was correct in that the scale argument needs to be an odd number. The default window is rectangle so scale is in pixel units.

Comment: The different meaning of scale needs documenting in ?tpi - now who is the maintainer...  ah! Now, where's the bug tracker!?

Comment: I have alread changed the help documentation for tpi to clarify this. I am actually quite open to fedback on functions as associated documentation so, there is need to be contrary. I am seeing more and more often, absoutly no help in r packages, just templet place holders to pass the cran check.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound contrary, sorry, but code on github with an issue tracker is becoming almost ubiquitous now. You should also try and get spatialEco mentioned in the spatial task view, this is the first I've seen it. Getting off topic now.

Comment: Done and done. I already had one package up on GitHub but I got everything relevant added and will also create repositories for some work in development as well (https://github.com/jeffreyevans). Any idea on whom I contact to get added to the spatial and machine learning task views? Rodger Bivand, Uwe Ligges?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your window type, as per the documentation [Topographic Position Index (Tpi)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatialEco/versions/0.1-7/topics/tpi)

`tpi(x, scale = 3, win = "rectangle", normalize = FALSE)`

These are the typical arguements that should be included

Arguments

**x**    -    A raster class object
**scale**   -   The focal window size
**win** -   Window type. Options are "rectangle" and "circle"
**normalize**   -   Apply deviation correction that normalizes to local surface roughness

Comment: Thank you, @whyzar. I tried and indeed, this works for `scale = 3`. However, when I tried larger scale values, I got this:


`> tpi(height, scale = 150, win = "rectangle", normalize = FALSE)


Error in .local(x, ...) : w must have uneven sides`

or
`> tpi(height, scale = 150, win = "circle", normalize = FALSE)


Error in tpi(height, scale = 150, win = "circle", normalize = FALSE) : 
  Scale is too small for a circular window`


So: do I misinterpret `scale`? My CRS is in m, so I thought `scale = 150` would return the tpi for 150 m search radius.

Comment: scale is the size in pixels - how many pixels is your data?

Comment: oh, ok.I have 426 x 422 Pixels but as you can see in the  image, much of this is empty.
As I know that one Pixel is about 80 m x 80 m, I could set `scale=2` in order to get a range of approx. 150 m? And would `win="circle"` make sense with such a small `scale` value?

Comment: What happens when you set the `scale = 2`?

Comment: I get `Error in .local(x, ...) : w must have uneven sides`. Now I understand - it only accepts uneven scale factors. I think I understood the funtion by now. feeling a bit stupid by now. However, thank you so much for your contribution!